# Cannot read property 'value' of null"

Tags: if-statement

https://jsfiddle.net/kxpzL13v/3/
go and have look on this when you click on a button genrate random story then error is occured .

````
  const name = customName.value;
  newStory=newStory.replace('Bob',name);
}```
````

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't link to third party code hosts in your question and instead make use of [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992) to embed it here.

Answer (score 0):

Your input looks like this

```
<input id="customeName" type="text" placeholder="">
```

so the id would be `customeName`

But you are referencing the input like this

`const customName = document.getElementById('customname');`

Correct above by adding the correct id `customeName` as below

`const customName = document.getElementById('customeName');`

Comment: no worries, those are normal, wishes for your learnings